# How to set reply format of email in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

On click of button event user can send the email.
For sending email,I used `mail.bodyformat = html`.I want user to reply me on same format(either html/txt which I used).While sending a email I want to set reply format of email.What shall I write for that?

Comment: Surely, the user can reply in whatever format that choose (and set up their e-mail client to use)?

Answer (score 1):

that is not possible, by the way look at this article

[custom headers for emails](http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/technical/)